# Custom logs folder path for each airflow DAG

Tags: airflow

I know airflow supports logging into S3/GCS/Azure etc.,

But is there a way to log into specific folders inside this storage based on some configuration inside the DAGs?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow does not support this feature yet. There is a centralised log folder to be configured in `airflow.cfg` where all logs get saved irrespective of the dag